# Publishing a message to multiple RabbitMQ consumers

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

I've been building a webapp which uses RabbitMQ for jobs. There are 3-5 workers, which process data from a queue, and occasionally one worker needs to send a message to all workers.

I've been reading the RabbitMQ docs, but have had a lot of trouble finding anything useful.

When a new worker starts, it generates a UUID (v6), and then subscribes to the queue `worker.{id}`, for example, `worker.7a277e65-8df4-4670-99b4-52c13478831d`.

From other questions, I've been able to work out that I need to create a topic exchange to allow workers to publish a message to `worker.*`, to have it sent to every worker.

However, I'm unsure on how this should be done. I'm using [jackrabbit](https://github.com/hunterloftis/jackrabbit), which does not support creating exchanges programatically, so I'll need to do it through the RabbitMQ management console, which looks like this:

[image]

Could you advise on the type of exchange I should create, and the parameters, and perhaps a usage example if it cannot be addressed like a usual queue?

Answer (score 0):

If Jackrabbit doesn't allow you to specify the exchanges, queues or bindings, then you need to find another library.

The problem is going to be your bindings. You can create an exchange, a queue and a binding from the management UI, as you've seen. But with Jackrabbit creating worker-specific queues, you won't be able to create bindings between your exchange and the queues that Jackrabbit creates.

I use, and highly recommend, the [wascally](https://github.com/LeanKit-Labs/wascally) library. It is built on top of amqplib, the same as Jackrabbit, but provides much more feature-rich API and capabilities.

As an example of how to use Wascally... set up three files with this code:

**config.json**

```
{
  "connection": {
    "user": "test",
    "pass": "password",
    "server": "localhost",
    "vhost": "test-app"
  },

  "exchanges":[
    {"name": "sample-ex.1", "type": "direct"}
  ],

  "queues":[
    {"name": "sample-q.1"}
  ],

  "bindings":[
    {"exchange": "sample-ex.1", "target": "sample-q.1"}
  ]
}
```

**receiver.js**

```
var rabbit = require("wascally");
var config = require("config.json");

rabbit.configure(config)
  .then(function(){
    rabbit.handle("test.message.type", handleMessage);
    rabbit.startSubscription("sample-q.1");
  })
  .then(undefined, reportError);

function reportError(err){
  console.log(err.stack);
  process.exit();
}

function handleMessage(msg){
  var body = msg.body;

  console.log("received a message");
  console.log(body);
  msg.ack();

  setTimeout(function(){
    // do work
  }, 5000);
}
```

**sender.js**

```
var rabbit = require("wascally");
var config = require("config.json");

rabbit.configure(config)
  .then(function(){
    rabbit.publish("sample-ex.1", {
      type: "test.message.type",
      routingKey: "",
      body: {
        foo: "bar"
      }
    });
  })
  .then(undefined, reportError);

function reportError(err){
  console.log(err.stack);
  process.exit();
}
```

now you can create as many instances of the receiver as you want. just run `node receiver.js` a few times.

then run `node sender.js` a few times, and you'll see the messages coming through the receivers - one receiver gets one message, and rabbitmq will round-robin the messages to the receivers.

---

p.s. this code comes from the screencasts in my [RabbitMQ For Devs](http://rabbitmq4devs.com/) package, if you're interested.